# Run php script with cronjob

Tags: php, linux, path, cron

so this is my cronjob

```
PATH=/package/host/localhost/php-5.4.7-1/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
PHPRC=/home/stuff/etc
* * * * * php /home/stuff/private/xFEklnTekl/cmd.php
```

and this is the cmd.php file

```
<?php
$c = file("c.txt");
$f = fopen("c.txt", "w+");
$g = $c[0]+1;
fwrite($f, $g);
fclose($f);
?>
```

Sadly it doesn't update the c.txt file as it should. I think something is wrong with the given path in the php script. I've already tried just /c.txt but it didn't work either. So, what might be wrong?

Comment: call cmd.php from the command line - any out output? does it work?

Comment: Maybe the permissions of the text file

Comment: @Dagon running it from the command line works perfectly. I'm not sure from where the cronjob runs the php file, that's why I don't know form where to point the c.txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your crontab shouldn't contain anything apart from cronjobs. Try using this:

```
* * * * * /bin/php /home/stuff/private/xFEklnTekl/cmd.php
```

And be sure you have +x permissions to execute, as well as crontab user has access to the directory.

Also, put full paths in

```
$c = file("c.txt");
$f = fopen("c.txt", "w+");
```

to

```
$c = file("/home/stuff/private/xFEklnTekl/c.txt");
$f = fopen("/home/stuff/private/xFEklnTekl/c.txt", "w+");
```

**Edit**
As seen on the comments, instead of `/bin/php` you have to use whatever comes from `which php`. In your case,

```
* * * * * /package/host/localhost/php-5.4.4/bin/php  /home/stuff/private/xFEklnTekl/cmd.php
```

Comment: I just got a mail saying `/bin/sh: bin/php: No such file or directory`, did and checked everything else and it's still not working. Thanks tho!

Comment: The command you put in crontab should work itself. So you firstly make sure it works and then put it in crontab. To know the route of php, type `which php`. It will be something like `/bin/php`, `/usr/bin/php`, etc. This is the route you will have to use to execute your script.

Comment: Thanks! `* * * * * /package/host/localhost/php-5.4.4/bin/php /home/albin/private/xFEklnTekl/cmd.php` worked perfectly!

Comment: Great! I edit my answer to include our comments : ) Mark the question as answered if now everything is working!

Comment: Done! Just another question about cronjobs and php. Will this cronjob run the file just as I would do it manually with the console like "php -f file.php" or will the cronjob execute something like a cURL request? My "real" cmd.php file needs to run for about 2 hours (sleep() function).

Comment: The cronjob will do exactly what the command says. So if you crontab `* * * * * /package/host/localhost/php-5.4.4/bin/php /home/albin/private/xFEklnTekl/cmd.php` it will do `/package/host/localhost/php-5.4.4/bin/php /home/albin/private/xFEklnTekl/cmd.php` every minute. If you want to  change the periodicity, take in account the format `* * * * *` stands for `minute month day_of_month month day_of_week`.